# Windows 10 Activation Key problems

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

My computer was unable to complete installation with the MCT from Microsoft. I did the iso install from Microsoft Tech Bench, and I do not have an activation key? How can i get one. I was upgrading from 8.1 pro (activated and authorized for free upgrade).

Comment: Did you perform an actual upgrade or a clean install?

Comment: Both the answers given below are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, update your new Windows 10 to the latest version since the 1511 version of Windows 10 (November 2015 Update) allows you to enter your old Windows 8.1 key to activate Windows 10. So enter the 8.1 key in system properties.

To check your Windows version, you can type "winver" in the start menu and the About Windows box will pop up :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are upgrading or have previously upgraded to Windows 10 and the upgrade was activated by Microsoft you do not need an activation key.

If you have no product activation key, you can install from scratch (wiping the drive and re-installing) only if you have previously upgraded or installed Windows 10 and activated it.

When installing from scratch, at the beginning of installation it asks if you have a product key.  Just click the correct answer.  If you have no key, the windows installation will check for a previous activation on your computer and automatically re-activate it for you.